# Boarder extraction on multidimensional array's data

Tags: c#

I want to change "1" into "0" inside the Pattern.
In given code I had been tried all the possible logic. Which can not working properly. I comment all the logic. Please check it one by one and define whats wrong with it.

Regards.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[,] a =    { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 },  
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
                            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};

            int r, c;
            for (r = 0; r < 10; r++)
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}  ", a[r, c]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");

            }//For Printing...


            r = 0;
            c = 0;
            for (r = 0; r < 10; r++)// it is coding for changing row position
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)// it is coding for changing column position
                {
                    if (a[r, c] != 0)// here i check position in array is not equal to zero.
                    {
                        int q, w, e, t, g, s, d, f;

                        q = a[r - 1, c];//Up
                        w = a[r + 1, c];//down
                        e = a[r, c - 1];//left
                        t = a[r, c + 1];//right
                        g = a[r + 1, c + 1];//down,right/* These all condintions are design for check circular surround of arrays position.*/
                        s = a[r + 1, c - 1];//down,left
                        d = a[r - 1, c + 1];//Up,right
                        f = a[r - 1, c - 1];//up,left


                        /*These are all possible logics which should be possibly made for checking around the position of array. If you want to check it, active one by one by removing comment*/

                        //if (q != 0 || w != 0 || e != 0 || t != 0 || g != 0 || s != 0 || d != 0 || f != 0)
                        //if (q != 0 && w != 0 && e != 0 && t != 0 && g != 0 && s != 0 && d != 0 && f != 0)

                        //if (q != 0 || w != 0 || e != 0 || t != 0 )
                        //if (q != 0 && w != 0 && e != 0 && t != 0 )

                        //if (q == 0 || w == 0 || e == 0 || t == 0 || g == 0 || s == 0 || d == 0 || f == 0)
                        //if (q == 0 && w == 0 && e == 0 && t == 0 && g == 0 && s == 0 && d == 0 && f == 0)

                        //if (q == 0 || w == 0 || e == 0 || t == 0 )
                        //if (q == 0 && w == 0 && e == 0 && t == 0 )

                        //if (q == 1 || w == 1 || e == 1 || t == 1 || g == 1 || s == 1 || d == 1 || f == 1)
                        //if (q == 1 && w == 1 && e == 1 && t == 1 && g == 1 && s == 1 && d == 1 && f == 1)

                        //if (q == 1 || w == 1 || e == 1 || t == 1 )
                        //if (q == 1 && w == 1 && e == 1 && t == 1 )

                        //if (q != 1 || w != 1 || e != 1 || t != 1 || g != 1 || s != 1 || d != 1 || f != 1)
                        //if (q != 1 && w != 1 && e != 1 && t != 1 && g != 1 && s != 1 && d != 1 && f != 1)

                        //if (q != 1 || w != 1 || e != 1 || t != 1 )
                        //if (q != 1 && w != 1 && e != 1 && t != 1 )


                        {
                            a[r, c] = 0;
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            /*Further below coding is for Output*/
            Console.Write("\n\n");

            for (r = 0; r < 10; r++)
            {
                for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}  ", a[r, c]);
                }

                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The required result..

```
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0   
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0  
             0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0  
             0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 
             0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0  
             0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: My, that's a big Wall O' Code you got there! Instead, try simplifying the problem, reducing your code to a minimal example, identify exactly where it is going wrong and what about its behavior is incorrect, then ask a specific question.

Comment: Remove those comment lines, and add the output you code generates.

Comment: i want to change 1 to zero inside the triangle of ones.

Comment: I add required result in my post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to empty rectangle from 1's we should determine the start and the end of rows that containing that rectangle. After that we iterate from row 3 of the rectangle, because the two first rows do not need change, and we find the start and end of  columns of current row. After finding those two, we transform 1's to 0's just after the start to just before the end. We continue the iterations to just before the last row.

```
int startI = 0, endI = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)//find start and end for rows
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
       if (a[i, j] == 1)
       {
           endI = i;//whenever you see 1, update it
           if (startI == 0)//Update just the first time you see 1
               startI = i;
       }
    }
}
//Make changes to all rows except the first one and the last one
for (int i = startI + 1; i < endI ; i++)
{
    int startJ = 0, endJ = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++)//find start and end for columns
    {
        if (a[i, j] == 1)
        {
            endJ = j;
            if (startJ == 0)
               startJ = j;
        }
    }
    //set all 1 to 0, except the first and the last for this row
    for (int j = startJ + 1; j < endJ ; j++)
        a[i, j] = 0;
}
```

What I understand from your code, you tried to find a square around each element and then decide based on the square elements values. Something like this(x is the current element)

```
f  q  d 
e  x  t
s  w  g
```

there are many combinations for this variables, so I comment on the last condition you checked

```
if (q != 1 || w != 1 || e != 1 || t != 1 ) 
   a[r, c] = 0;
```

this condition fails for example when we have(sets the x = 0 wrongly)

```
0  0  1
0 x=1 1
1  1  1
```

**Note:** This code just works for convex shapes.

Comment: Thanks T.Rahgooy. its correct and i appriciate your efforts. But i want to find out error in my coding.. again thanks.

Comment: Your code is not very clear, can you give some explanations about how you want to solve the problem?( like what I made above). You declared many variables and did not use them, remove them, in order to help the reader  to have a better idea about the code.

Comment: Actually  i don't want to use "GetLength" in loop. I want to do it from simple loop. Just like i use in my coding..

Comment: just replace them by 10 and that's it

Comment: @MuhammedNaqi, I changed the code to work with every shape you want.

Comment: Yes its working properly.....................Thank you...................................